# How can I get public transport maps in WKT format?

Tags: openstreetmap, xml, well-known-text, transportation

I can get street maps from [openstreetmaps.org](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) (XML) and convert it into WKT with the tool osm2wkt.

There are several people creating specialist public transport maps:

- The Transport Map layer on OSM's front page by Andy Allan
- Öpnvkarte (öpnvkarte.de) (Also available at openbusmap.org for those with no Ö accessible}
- Openptmap (openptmap.org)
- OpenStreetBrowser (openstreetbrowser.org)
- OSMTransport (3liz.fr) - as per city javascript overlays
- LatLon.org's public transport layer
- OpenMap.lt public transport layer
- OSM Transport Karte Map for Trucks and Cars

However, there is no way to get the XML or WKT format map. **How do I get public transport maps in WKT format?**

Answer (score 1):

[Public transport is made](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Public_transport) out of the basic elements of OSM. Nodes for the stops, ways for the highway-segments and relations as containers to group all together for the single public transport routes. Thus it has a more detailed level of data than what you like to consume.

So you need to create a processing that matchs your requirements. You can use pretty different tools that are able to filter and transform OSM geodata. Some example workflows are:

- [OpenPTMap setup](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Openptmap/Installation)
- [Overpass PT example](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API#Public_transport_example)
- [Maperitive PT mapstyle](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/User:Rotbarsch/Maperitive_rules/public_transport)
- ...

So you will need filter->transformer->exporter and get WKT. But simply using [osm2wkt](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2wkt) (which is AFAIK not well known at the community just doesn't work ;-)

Comment: thx a lot. I am working on it. Further, how can I get a remote village map?

Answer (score 0):

Just placing this here : a nifty python script https://github.com/KaunilD/osm2wkt which will convert as the name says an osm to a wkt.